# How to interact with my smart contract on web browser

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I deployed my contract on ropsten.
And I tried to interact with it on browser but error message said that it is not a function.
I already tried at NodeJS and there was no error. So the contract address or ABI file isn't wrong.

This is my code. Is there an error here?

```
const address = 'Contract addresss';
const myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, address);
let result = await myContract.methods.createDoc('asdf').call();
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this line

```
let result = await myContract.methods.createDoc('asdf').call();
```

To either one of these:

```
let result = await myContract.methods.createDoc().call('asdf');

let result = await myContract.methods.createDoc('asdf');
```